# ROS not properly installed?

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, ros

newbie here. I installed ROS humble on both my Raspberry Pi and my laptop which both runs Ubuntu OS 22.04 (VMware on laptop). I followed instructions from the website and a guy from YouTube. I tried running the Talker Listener (listener on laptop) but it wasn't receiving anything. I also tried running roscore but an error message appeared saying that roscore stopped unexpectedly. this also happened when I asked chatgpt to give me an example code for talker listener and gave me the code rostopic echo /test_topic but an error message saying that rostopic stopped unexpectedly also appeared.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot2]